# Is there a book which develops real analysis axiomatically using second order logic?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, real-numbers

Is there a book which develops real analysis axiomatically using formal second order logic?  I have only ever heard of real analysis being developed by coding real numbers in second order arithmetic, or by coding integers in set theory and then coding real numbers from those integers.  I don't have a philosophical problem with coding real numbers in another system, but it seems like a lot of extra work.  Is there an approach that just goes straight to real numbers axiomatically?

Comment: Isn't this essentially what the standard axiomatization of $\mathbb{R}$ as a complete ordered field does?

Comment: It is.  But I've never seen anyone introduce a second order deduction system and then start proving theorems from the complete ordered field axioms.

Comment: Only because most textbooks would not bother introducing any kind of deduction system at all...

Comment: Note that even in the second-order theory of the reals, you will still need some substantial coding to do analysis.  For instance, you need to encode functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as sets of reals.

Comment: Some types of second order logic only allow quantifying over predicates/subsets.  Others also allow quantifying over functions.  As far as I know those systems then introduce an axiom to translate between functions and subsets.

Comment: I've heard of formal analysis being carried on high-order proof assistants, like HOL-light or Isabelle. Maybe this link (Formalization of Real Analysis: A Survey of Proof Assistants and Libraries - https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00806920v1/document ) could be of interest to you.